# MakeHuman Character bends over after retargeting w MoCap

Tags: animation, rigging, makehuman, motion-capture

I'm trying to animate a MakeHuman character with self captured motion from [Perception Neuron](https://neuronmocap.com/). The motion looks good in Axis Neuron but when exported and retargeted in Blender, the upper body bends forward 90° and the arms hang down, while the rest stays in shape. Can anyone help me with this problem?

[image]

Thank you in advance,

Max

Comment: Is that the rest pose?

Comment: no, the rest pose is a t pose